# How can identify when the other party has answered a call with PJSIP?

Tags: c++, voip, pjsip

I am using PJSUA2 with the new c++ high level api.

I want to play a pre-recorded .wav message after the other party has answered the call. So far, PJSIP's onCallState() supports a number of events, limited to the SIP part of the call, which means that after the session part is done (e.g. the other end is ringing), the only other event to recognize is the `PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED` one.

What I am trying to do, is identify whether the other party has actually answered the call. I thought of trying to peek at the RTP side, but have not found anything so far and the documentation is not really helpful.

Anyone has done this before?

edit:

This is the code when the call is ended.

```cpp
void MyCall::onCallState(OnCallStateParam& prm) {

    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(prm);

    CallInfo ci = getInfo();
    std::cout << "*** Call: " << ci.remoteUri << " [" << ci.stateText << "]" << std::endl;
    if ( ci.state == PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED )
    {
        //myAcc->removeCall(this);
        /* Delete the call */
        //delete this;
        myAcc->removeCall(this);
        delete this;
        return;
    }
}
```

The sip part ends when the invite has been sent to the other side.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @nurgasemetey updated the initial post

Answer (score 0):

Check state on equal to PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONNECTING and PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONFIRMED as established call.

https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSIP__INV.htm#ga083ffd9c75c406c41f113479cc1ebc1c

And check not in CallState, but in CheckMediaState as when answering an incoming call: https://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/call.html#working-with-call-s-audio-media

Comment: This is on the SIP end. The invite / confirmation of the, applies only until the other end is ringing, not if the call is answered

Answer (score 0):

If connection establishet you get media point. And can play you .wav file:

```
void MyCall::onCallMediaState(OnCallMediaStateParam &prm)
{
    CallInfo ci = getInfo();
    // Iterate all the call medias
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < ci.media.size(); i++) {
        if (ci.media[i].type==PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO && getMedia(i)) {
            AudioMedia *aud_med = (AudioMedia *)getMedia(i);

            AudioMediaPlayer player;
            try {
                player.createPlayer("file.wav");
                player.startTransmit(*aud_med);
            } catch(Error& err) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly, this will start playing `file.wav` right after the SIP connection is established, not when the call is answered. The SIP identifies an established connection as the response to an invite. Immediately after that point in your solution, the file will start playing and the other end starts ringing, which means that when the other end actually picks up, it will have missed some of the message.

Comment: Please attempt.

Comment: Just did. The code you suggested will not work actually because the AudioMediaPlayer object will be destroyed when out of scope. With the AudioMediaPlayer outside the scope, the wav file starts playing immediately after the other end starts ringing which confirms my previous comment

Comment: Maybe. Make the player part of the class. And you may need to deal with multithreading.

Comment: And check answer status code: 180 or 183. 183 with media. 180 without.